# SQLite error in objective-c(IOS app development)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cordova, sqlite

I am using the following code to open database in SQLite and execute an insert query.

```
// Open the database and store the handle as a data member
if (sqlite3_open([databaseFile UTF8String], &databaseHandle) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    const char *sqlStatement = [insertStmt cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    char *error;

    if (sqlite3_exec(databaseHandle, sqlStatement, NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Config table values inserted.");
        registration_done = YES;
    } 
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %s", error);
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]]; 

        if (sqlite3_exec(databaseHandle, sqlStatement, NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"Config table values inserted 2.");
            registration_done = YES;
        } 
        else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %s", error);
        }
    }
}
else{

    sqlite3_close(databaseHandle);
}

sqlite3_close(databaseHandle);
```

But I am getting following error and the app is terminating after that:

> -[__NSCFType UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15d9a0

Database files and tables are created in the /Caches/ directory as I am using Phonegap(2.1.0). Phonegap is properly executing query prior to above Objective-C code being called, which means that tables are getting created successfully in the /Caches/ directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
const char *sqlStatement = [insertStmt UTF8String];
```

Comment: Ya i tried this.. So the above mentioned error is not coming, but the app is still terminating.

Comment: Can you switch on additional debug (such as zombie objects) information and show me the error message?

Comment: 0x3e9c:  ldr    r1, [sp, #220] and comment in green is EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: problem should be here: if (sqlite3_open([databaseFile UTF8String], &databaseHandle) == SQLITE_OK) or here: if (sqlite3_exec(databaseHandle, sqlStatement, NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK)

Comment: You can check it so easy - Just run debug and take a look row when error occurs. Also could you please check if databaseFile is a NSString and it contains path for DB

Comment: Sorry i am a bit new to objective-c and i don't understand what u mean by look row..Anyways databaseFile is NSString and contains path for db ie. /Library/Caches/file__0/0000000000000001.db.

Comment: I enabled zombie and got following message:  *** -[NSPathStore2 UTF8String]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1456f0 and tried to print memory for databaseFile, it came the same. So, that means databaseFile gets deallocated before itself. So how should i declare it. Right now i am declaring it as NSString *databaseFile; And just to let u know, i am using ARC.

Answer (score 0):

@clint:- Please, read this [URL](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html)

or Try this Example this is really working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Contact Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Populate the database 
    //
    function populateDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
    }

    // Query the database
    //
    function queryDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
    }

    // Query the success callback
    //
    function querySuccess(tx, results) {
        var len = results.rows.length;
        console.log("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");
        for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
            console.log("Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).id + " Data =  " + results.rows.item(i).data);
        }
    }

    // Transaction error callback
    //
    function errorCB(err) {
        console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
    }

    // Transaction success callback
    //
    function successCB() {
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
    }

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Database</p>
  </body>
</html>
```